# Plotting fits from scipy.optimize.curve_fit and changing the line format

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

I have been trying to do some fits with curve_fit and have run into an issue where I can't change the format of the line being plotted. When I run the following code, an 'AttributeError: Unknown property fmt' is thrown on the third line.

```
plt.errorbar(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2], data[:,3], fmt=format_data, label='Original data')
x_range = np.linspace(np.amin(data[:,0]), np.amax(data[:,0]), 100)
plt.plot(x_range, linear_fit(x_range, *fit[0][0]), label = 'Linear Fit', fmt='mo')
```

Where data is a numpy array that contains my x, y, xerr, and yerr data, and fit is the return of the curve_fit operation.

If i remove the fmt arg, it plots everything fine and chooses a default format. I assume this is something to do with plt.plot behaving differently when you are plotting the return of a function. I know that I can call .color and .marker on the line object returned by plt.plot but would rather not have to.

Is there any fix to this?

Comment: `fmt` is not a valid keyword argument for `plt.plot`. You can see that from the [function signature](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html). One option is to specify the format as positional argument,  `plt.plot(x,y,'mo')`; the other option is to use the individual properties, `plt.plot(x,y,color='m', marker='o')`.

Comment: Yup, that was a silly mistake. Thanks!